# Dynamic reference casting depending on actual object type

Tags: java, dynamic, reflection

I have classes hierarchy such as

```
ChildA extends Parent
ChildB extends Parent
ChildC extends Parent
```

then in my application, I get in a method any of this child by Parent reference.

The problem is all of these children have the same methods but their parent doesn't

So, `ChildA, ChildB, and ChildC` all have `getSomeValue()` getter but `Parent` doesn't.

Now I need to parse the value from any of this child, but Parent reference doesn't provide me with API so I need to cast Parent to specific children type.

Below is the snippet representing what I am trying to do:

```
private void processChildren(Parent parent) {
    ChildA childA = null;
    ChildB childB = null;
    ChildC childC = null;

    if (parent instanceof ChildA) {
        childA = parent;
    }

    if (parent instanceof ChildB) {
        childB = parent;
    }

    if (parent instanceof ChildC) {
        childC = parent;
    }

    String someValue;

    if (Objects.nonNull(childA)) {
        someValue = childA.getSomeValue();
    } // and the same checks and extracts for each of childs and for many methods

}
```

As you can see in order to extract just one value I need to create 3 references, then check them in order to cast to specific type and then check what the type actually was created in order to call the method.

The question is how to properly cast the reference to the specific child reference in runtime?
I guess it is possible to write using reflection, although I was not able to solve it even with reflection.

Also, even if it possible - is it ok to do that?

FYI: I am working on a legacy application so I can't change the previously written code so I can't add this API in Parent class. Also, the classes are provided from an external jar.

Comment: Can you change the reference of the Parent to a different subClass which the children extend from? Something like ChildA --> SubParent --> Parent

Comment: You can use instanceof operator to check the exact instance type

Comment: Could you add a code example how you _get in a method any on this children by Parent reference_?

Comment: What is the return type of `getSomeValue()`?

Comment: does it matter? String

Comment: Yes ... it's in the code of your question - sorry.

Comment: You either need to use reflection or go with casting. If you have small finite set of subclasses then go with casting otherwise if performance is not at issue just call that method via reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a possible solution you can create a map parametrized by specific child Class as a key, and supplier as a value. Each supplier is responsible for casting and dealing with particular methods.

```
Map<Class<? extends Parent>, Supplier> getValueMap = new HashMap<>();

getValueMap.put(ChildA.class, () -> { return ((ChildA) parent).getValue(); });
getValueMap.put(ChildB.class, () -> { return ((ChildB) parent).getValue(); });
getValueMap.put(ChildC.class, () -> { return ((ChildC) parent).getValue(); });

getValueMap.get(parent.getClass()).get();
```

Comment: Wow! Great Solution! :) Although you do have to make entries in the Map for each child class.

Answer (score 0):

> The question is how to properly cast the reference that definitely is
>   the one of this types to the specific reference?

Use instanceof operator to check the exact instance type of the Parent reference.

```
    if (parent instanceof ChildA) {
        ChildA childA = (ChildA) parent;
    } else if (parent instanceof ChildB) {
        ChildB childB = (ChildB) parent;
    } else if (parent instanceof ChildC) {
        ChildC childAC = (ChildC) parent;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but question contains word "properly" so if  I will have a hundred children than with your solution I will have a very long method. I am looking for a good solution

Comment: Can you subClass the Parent like I asked in the previous comment? ChildA --> SubParent --> Parent and then use SubParent reference in your application instead of Parent reference.

Comment: sorry, this classes are provided from external jar so I do not have access to them

Comment: Do you mean all the classes i.e. all Children and Parent are from external jar?

Comment: Yes. I can just use them in any way but not change

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that all the children have the getSomeValue method, you could call them as

```
parent.getClass().getMethod("getSomeValue").invoke(parent);
```

However, this is not a good practice. The class design violates Liskov's substitution principle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle%20%22Read%20here).

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to do as I would extend `Parent` by the missing interface. To do so I'm defining an interface which declares the missing methods:

```
public interface HasSomeValue {

    String getSomeValue();

}
```

As it's impossible to let `Parent` itself implement this interface I define a wrapper for `Parent`:

```
private static class ParentWithSomeValue implements HasSomeValue {

    private Parent parent;

    public ParentWithSomeValue(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSomeValue() {
        try {
            Method method = parent.getClass().getMethod("getSomeValue");
            return (String) method.invoke(parent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover `ParentWithSomeValue` delegates to other methods which `Parent` already has. Then `ParentWithSomeValue` provides the full interface of `Parent` and can replace it.

`getSomeValue` is implemented using reflection. If `parent` has the called method then the call is delegated to `parent` using reflections. Otherwise a default value is returned. In my example `null`. Another option would be to throw an exception if `parent` has to have the called method.

Using this approach you can also extend the implemented interface or add more interfaces and implement the delegation on a per method basis.

Applying this to your code:

```
private void processChildren(Parent parent) {
    if (Objects.nonNull(parent)) {
        ParentWithSomeValue parentWithSomeValue = new ParentWithSomeValue(parent);
        String someValue = parentWithSomeValue.getSomeValue();
        // go on
    } 
}
```